# Jface Table row validation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

**Background:**
I have a Jface table on which I have set Editing support with text cell editor for each column. There are around 20 columns.

**Problem:**
I want to highlight invalid row field text with dark red color and whole row with light red color.

**What I tried as of now:**
1. I have highlighted invalid field(single cell of row) using label providers getBackgroundColor() and getForgroundColor().
2. I tried CellEditors setValidator() method to add a validator, but I don't want to clear invalid text from a cell, I just want to highlight it.
3. I have one approach to use a flag for each cell to check the validity of that cell if any of the flags is true will highlight all cells of that row(can be achieved using label providers). But, I think this approach will impact performance for my table.
4. I am not sure performance impact of table updatatestrategy of Jface. So I am not using it.

**Reason of highlighting the whole row of the table is:** Table have 20+ columns and user don't want to scroll the table to find out problem location.

Please suggest if you know any better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using label providers to for the colors is the  way to do this.

The label provider is only asked for the color when the row is created or refreshed - by calling one of the viewer `refresh` or `update` methods, so this should not impact performance.

Comment: Thanks Gerg, just wanted to confirm the approach #3 from my question(section - What I tried as of now) is the only way, in Jface?

Comment: Basically yes it is the only way. Label providers are what you use for colors.